# How to delete document from index by it's path in Whoosh

Tags: python, whoosh

First i add documents to index like this:

```
writer.add_document(title=doc_path.split(os.sep)[-1], path=doc_path, content=text, textdata=text)
```

And then i just need to delete one of them completely from index by it's path. Documentation says there are few no low level method to do this:

> delete_by_term(fieldname, termtext)
>
> Deletes any documents where the given (indexed) field contains the
>   given term. This is mostly useful for ID or KEYWORD fields.
>
> delete_by_query(query)
>
> Deletes any documents that match the given query.

but i can't find suitable and very convenient method for me where i can specify path of the document and just remove it. There is some low level method where i can specify internal doc_number, which i supposed to get somehow.
Can anyone give me advice how it's better to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

```
ix = open_dir('/my_index_dir_path/..')
writer = ix.writer()
writer.delete_by_term('path', doc_path)
writer.commit()
```

> delete_by_term

method does exactly what i need. Note, that first argument is a text string 'path', and them goes the actual path. My mistake was to put an actual path instead of attribute name.

Comment: It's always better to add some explanation to the answer. Please edit it and improve your answer.